# Is it possible to add more than four answer options to exams2nops exams?

Tags: r, r-exams

Is it possible to have more than 4 answer options on exams2nops exams? I tried to set the option `nchoice = 6` but it did not produce any effect. I have 6 answer options in the correspondent `*.rmd` exercise.

One example:

```
exams2nops(questions, n = 1, nsamp = 1, encoding = "UTF-8",  blank = 0,  nchoice = 6, duplex = T, reglength = 5L, points = 4, replacement = T,schoice = list(eval = ee))
```

And the exercise `*.rmd`:

````
```{r}
df <- readRDS(file = "some.rds")

variable <- names(df[,4:7]) %>% sample(1)

measCT<- ifelse(variable==names(df)[4],"Mean",
        ifelse(variable==names(df)[5],"Mean",
           ifelse(variable==names(df)[6],"Median",
              ifelse(variable==names(df)[7],"Median",NaN))))


measuresTC <- c("Mode", "Percentile 25", "Percentile 75", "Median", "Mean", "Geometric mean")

options_answers <- paste0(c(measCT,measuresTC[!measuresTC %in% measCT]))
solutions <- c(T,F,F,F,F,F)
```


Question
========

`r paste0("Some question about the ", variable)`


```{r questionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
exams::answerlist(unlist(options_answers), markup = "markdown")
```


Meta-information
================
exname: 1_1
extype: schoice
exsolution: `r paste(solutions, collapse = "|")`
exshuffle: 4
````

The produced pdf always presents four options...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

Currently, `exams2nops()` only supports up to five choice alternatives.

### Further comments

Optionally supporting more choice alternatives is on the wishlist for NOPS exercises but it's not very likely to be implemented in the near(er) future. (Changes in NOPS exercises require quite a bit of work because generation, scanning, and evaluation all have to be in sync and thoroughly tested etc.)

In your example, there are always exactly four choice alternatives because you set `exshuffle` to 4. Thus, always four alternatives are randomly selected. If you want five alternatives, you can set it to `exshuffle: 5`. And if you specify a number > 5 then you get a warning from `exams2nops()`:

> Error in exams2nops(questions) :
> the following exercises have length < 2 or > 5: ...

Setting the `nchoice` argument has no effect because it is not an argument that you can set in `exams2nops()` but an argument for `make_nops_template()`. When you call `exams2nops()` internally the following steps happen:

1. Determine how many choice alternatives there are per exercise.
2. Set up a LaTeX template with the correct number of choices via `make_nops_template()`.
3. Call `exams2nops(..., template = ...)` with the template created in the previous step.

Comment: Can you please add an implementation of that to my example? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean here. You can set `exshuffle: 5` instead of `4` in the exercise. Then you get 5 random choice alternatives.

Comment: I change the `exshuffle` from `4` to `5` and I changed the number of solutions from 6 to 5, however... I receive this message:


`length of exsolution and questionlist does not match in '1_1'5 shuffled answers requested, only 4 available in '1_1'`

Comment: I cannot say for sure for your example because it isn't self-contained. But I just noticed that `exsolution` is misspecified, it should be: `exsolution: 'r mchoice2string(solutions)'`. Or in this case you could also hard-code: `exsolution: 100000`. But once `exsolution` is corrected, setting `exshuffle: 5` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I changed the exsolution to `exsolution: 'r mchoice2string(solutions)'`. I have five options appearing... however, only one solution appears. The others are `NA`s (https://i.imgur.com/Ugo3q91.png).

Comment: Additionally, this warning appears: `length of exsolution and questionlist does not match in '1_1'`

Comment: Please create a new question because this is really not related to `exams2nops` at all. Also make sure that it is self contained. And please accept this answer, I think it is fully answered.